# Foreign key constraint fails with doctrine entities when importing database

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a big database to import (around 350 Mb). When trying to import this database with command-line mysql, I have this error :

```
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 5118296: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`tutotour_tharmobeta1`.`#sql-2039_195b4`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_D367B678BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `reponse` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

In this line in the SQL file, I have :

```
--
-- Contraintes pour la table `reponse`
--
ALTER TABLE `reponse`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC75DDDBC71` FOREIGN KEY (`error`) REFERENCES 
`errorcsv` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC78D93D649` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `user` 
(`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC7D6ADE47F` FOREIGN KEY (`epreuve`) REFERENCES 
`banque_epreuve_temporaire` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_5FB6DEC7DCC6487D` FOREIGN KEY (`passage_id`) REFERENCES 
`passer_colle` (`id`);

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `reponse_qc`
--
ALTER TABLE `reponse_qc`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_D367B678B6F7494E` FOREIGN KEY (`question`) REFERENCES 
`qc` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_D367B678BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `reponse` 
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `reponse_qr`
--
ALTER TABLE `reponse_qr`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_B9D7968A8D5FE0A2` FOREIGN KEY (`idCorrecteur`) REFERENCES 
`tuteur` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_B9D7968ABF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `reponse` 
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `reponse_qr_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idColle`) REFERENCES 
`colle_qr` (`id`);
```

My entities are defined as follows :

Reponse entity :

```
/**
 *  Réponse
 *
 * @ORM\Table("reponse")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PACES\ColleBundle\Repository\ReponseRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"reponse"="Reponse", "reponseQC"="ReponseQC", 
"reponseQR"="ReponseQR"})
 */
class Reponse
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\PACES\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="reponses", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $user;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\ErrorCSV", inversedBy="reponses", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="error", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $error;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(name="archive" , type="boolean" , nullable=false, options={"default" = false} )
 */
private $archive;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="banque", type="boolean", options={"default" = false})
 */
protected $banque;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\PasserColle", inversedBy="reponses", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $passage;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\BanqueBundle\Entity\BanqueEpreuveTemporaire", inversedBy="reponses", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="epreuve", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $epreuveTemporaire;
```

ReponseQC :

```
/**
 *  ReponseQC
 *
 * @ORM\Table("reponse_qc")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PACES\ColleBundle\Repository\ReponseQCRepository")
 */
class ReponseQC extends Reponse
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="QC", inversedBy="reponses", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $question;
```

Everything was working fine when I imported the same database before and I don't think I made any changes to the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    /* run your query here */
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    $connection->commit();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollback();
}
```

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: You might want to explain your answer a bit, before you get struck by downvotes.

Comment: That's what I thought about first but I think it's a workaround. It doesn't really solve the problem... And I forgot to say I'm importing the database with command-line mysql directly

Comment: @svgrafov The query you are trying to run is blocked by a foreign key constraint. I don't know what is that constraint, since i don't have the full database image, but if you are sure your query is ok, you can tell mysql to stop checking for this type of constraint, until you run your query, by calling $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0'); before you run your query. Also turn that check on after that with $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1'); If you think that this is not helpful and me trying to help requires a down vote feel free to do that.

Comment: @Kristen Joseph-Delaffon if you are running the query from mysql then doctrine has nothing to do with it. Also this is the way mysql behaves when you are trying to alter stuff over the foreign key constraint. You can use the same thing in command line. Run "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" run your query, then run SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1. There is no other way around this.

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi The error appears at the end of the import. All the data is already imported and it's at the end when importing all the foreign keys that it fails.

Comment: @Kristen Joseph-Delaffon can you give me more details about your sql file. Do you have Table create, table alter, inserts in it?

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi The SQL file is creating all the tables in the database, importing all the data in these and then alter tables to create foreign keys.

Comment: @Kristen Joseph-Delaffon It could be that you have a line in "reponse_qc" table with an id that is not found in the "reponse" Table. Move the foreign keys in front of the inserts. Also make sure you do the inserts into "response" before "reponse_qc". If I'm right this will trigger an error on the insert statement that adds this line to "reponse_qc".

Comment: @Kristen Joseph-Delaffon i did some testing and indeed, if your table "reponse_qc" has a line with an id that is not found in "reponse", trying to add a foreign key on "reponse_qc" will result in that error.

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi I checked in phpMyAdmin and something weird happens. When I check reponse_qc table and go to last results, I have some reponse_qc ids which are not in reponse table. But when I click on the id to go to parent reponse row, it's finding the row whereas I don't see it when I go to reponse table.

Comment: @Kristen Joseph-Delaffon do you have the same type on the foreign key from "reponse_qc" as you do on the primary key form "response"?

Comment: Actually, I had some rows in reponse_qc that didn't have parent in reponse table. I deleted these rows and I don't have any problem anymore. Thank you for your answers